# Property does not exist on type void

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, hook

I am writing a hook to make a post request that returns two properties, **sessionId** and **sessionData**. I am using this hook in a component. My hook looks like this.

```
export const createOrder = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await postWithToken(API_ROUTES.PAYMENT_SESSION, token || '', 
    testObject)
    console.log("FROM HOOK", response)
    return response
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

And my component look like this

```
const myComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    createOrder().then(data => {
      console.log("Session Data",data.sessionData)
      console.log("FROM PAGE", data)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div />
  )
}
```

When I try to access data.sessionData on the component I get the error that sessionDta does not exist on type void. But If I check the logs on the console I get the same object on the component and on the hook. Also If I check on my component the typeof data I get an object.

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: You don't return anything from your `catch` block, so the return type of your function is `WhateverTheTypeOfResponseIs | void`, depending on which code path happens. Are you using Javascript or Typescript? How/where did you get that error? VSCode intellisense?

Comment: Yes, the error comes from Intellisense and I am using Typescript.  It seems to me that `Promise<void>` is the default type inferred the Typescript compiler. When I try to type the return of the async function I get a "Type `WhateverTheTypeOfResponseIs` is not a valid `async` function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value". I am not landing either on the catch block since I get the object on the component when I call the hook `createOrder` from there. Actually if I check the type on my component I get also an object

Comment: I would suggest to move your error handling logic inside the `useEffect` hook when you call via `.catch`, e.g. `createOrder().then(...).catch(...)`. Then simplify your `createOrder` **function** to just simply `return postWithToken(...)`. Also, `createOrder` is not a `hook` - it's just a simple function.

Comment: Also, looks like you're using `TypeScript` and not providing the return type of `createOrder`, e.g. `createOrder = async (): Promise<SomeType>`, which is why it's complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't return anything from your catch block, so the return type of your function is `Promise<WhateverTheTypeOfResponseIs | void>` (N.B. `async` functions implicitly return a Promise, and if your `postWithToken` function doesn't return anything then it's just `Promise<void>`), depending on which code path happens.

In the future you can avoid unpleasant and slightly problematic to debug issues like this by giving your functions an explicit return type and in this case the compiler will let you know that your expectation was violated:

```js
const postWithToken = async (route: string, token: string, obj: any): Promise<boolean> => {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch(
      route,
      { 
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(Object.assign(obj, { token }))
      },
    )
    return Boolean(resp.status < 400 && resp.status >= 200)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return false
  }
}

const API_ROUTES = {
    PAYMENT_SESSION: 'whatever'
}

const testObject = {
  token: ''
}

const token = ''

const createOrder = async (): Promise<boolean> => { // <-- squiggles
  try {
    const response = await postWithToken(API_ROUTES.PAYMENT_SESSION, token || '', 
    testObject)
    console.log("FROM HOOK", response)
    return response
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBADiaB1AllAFgFRAawKZgwC8MAhhAJ5jAwAUATiAK5R4BcM09KYA5gDQwouAhy48BMEACMAVh1JgKASg4AFRgFsUEPAB5pIEABs8igHzFLAbwBQMIfQow7Dh6Eix6eCHGJkAd1I0GAAzPChgdFp7NwdGFjx+WLjrGBS4mE0I9BAAEw4AcjUAeQBlTELkzLdDPIoOACkykoA5ADpxPhRQiloSuTxgKHbyCBReMFoZWUE04XxCAF9lZQyHJeq3NbjvKCZ6QgAhI1NFBh84TqhSfYgYPRgAFgAGF5gAMg+Yb19r26Y93MJAATG8djAljBgLconQ8PR6MoXBkPBATHh2gjGPRaNiIfEIgdCKFSMZdLElrYqbY0bAAIJqACSAH0AEolACqmAAomV-K43Gp6QBNACyPNamBZZT5ZSZbSKAXQtzwADcEYVqbZaeBoEIfFABrIhrASIKFqIYIUtTS6UIRIQSDadfbgN5VSV6HkEf5yFQaLRVDANCBtLoDKczGBLEQbDAAPQJh4AWhTnAAjkwJrxTBBYlAnCi4vbfghIHg-UEQghkGgsI7aIzWRzuXz2sLxZLpbKyvK2oJLYQAD7D61VdJxVjQY2mgnQvUY9rGEC8WgAIgAYhyxTAABIlEoAaXXgjLerw872xJ+lwvlOhsPQ8MRCiUyMF7kXpmXq7xiIhKkqQcIA)

The types in the example I created may be different (you'll need to sub with the actual types from your code) but you should get the idea. You can fix this by any of the following:

1. Explicitly return something of the correct type from the catch block.
2. Change your return type to `Promise<CorrectType | undefined>`.
3. Move the error handling to the caller as suggested by goto1 in the comments.

Also note that as goto1 points out in the comments on the question, your hook isn't actually a hook (which is fine, but be careful of terminology).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a `TypeScript` issue, so I suggest to provide the proper return type for your `createOrder` function.

```js
// Use the official type for SessionData, if you have it available,
// otherwise create a new type that properly matches its shape
type CreateOrderResult = {
  sessionData: SessionData;
}

// No need for `async/await` here, just return the `postWithToken`
// and handle errors inside your component
export const createOrder = (): Promise<CreateOrderResult> => {
  // ...
  return postWithToken(
    API_ROUTES.PAYMENT_SESSION, 
    token || '',
    testObject
  )
}

// MyComponent.tsx
const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    createOrder()
      .then(data => console.log(data.sessionData))
      .catch(error => /* handle errors appropriately */)
  }, [])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

open tsconfig.json file and
change

"strict": true,

into

"strict": false,

this usually works for me

check out https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html for more information